# General solution of parabolic ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I consider the following ODE:
$$
\frac{\sigma^2}{2}  x^2  f''(x) + rxf'(x) + \frac{1}{x+1} f(x) = 0,
$$
where $\sigma$ and $r$ are some constants.

I want to find a general solution to this ODE.

I used WolframAlpha to find this solution and it returned the function of the form:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(s) &= c_2 s^{(\sqrt{4 r^2 - 4 r \sigma^2 + \sigma^4 - 8\sigma^2} - 2 r + \sigma^2)/(2 \sigma^2)} \\ &_2F_1\left(\frac{\sqrt{\sigma^4 - 4 r \sigma^2 - 8 \sigma^2 + 4 r^2} + 2r - \sigma^2}{2 \sigma^2}, \frac{\sqrt{\sigma^4 - 4 r \sigma^2 - 8 \sigma^2 + 4 r^2} - 2r + \sigma^2}{2 \sigma^2}, \frac{\sqrt{\sigma^4 - 4 r \sigma^2 - 8 \sigma^2 + 4 r^2}}{\sigma^2} + 1; -s\right) + \\ &c_1 s^{-(\sqrt{4 r^2 - 4 r \sigma^2 + \sigma^4 - 8 \sigma^2} + 2 r - \sigma^2)/(2 \sigma^2)} \\ &_2F_1\left(-\frac{\sqrt{\sigma^4 - 4 r \sigma^2 - 8 \sigma^2 + 4 r^2} + 2r - \sigma^2}{2 \sigma^2}, -\frac{\sqrt{\sigma^4 - 4 r \sigma^2 - 8 \sigma^2 + 4 r^2} - 2r + \sigma^2}{2 \sigma^2}, 1 - \frac{\sqrt{\sigma^4 - 4 r \sigma^2 - 8 \sigma^2 + 4 r^2}}{\sigma^2}; -s\right),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are some constants.

I am not sure if this solution is a general solution for any values $\sigma$ and $r$.

In other words, I suppose that for some values of $\sigma$ and $r$ both of the above addend are not linearly independent.

Can anybody help me with this problem or give a reference to this type of ODE?

Comment: Isn't this an ODE? I didn't understand why you used the word PDE

Comment: Yes, of course, you are right, it is ODE!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure what $\sigma$ is supposed to be in your solution, but if we define $$K=\frac{\sqrt{-8b^{2} +b^{4} -4b^{2} r+4r^{2}}}{2b^{2}}$$ And let $c_1$ and $c_2$ be arbitrary constants, Mathematica returned the following solution: $$f( x) =x^{K^\prime}\left( c_{1} \ F_{1}\left(\frac{1}{2} -\frac{r}{b^{2}} -K,-\frac{1}{2} +\frac{r}{b^{2}} -K,1-2K,-x\right) \\+c_{2} F_{1}\left(\frac{1}{2} -\frac{r}{b^{2}} +K,-\frac{1}{2} +\frac{r}{b^{2}} +K,1+2K,-x\right)\right)$$
Where $$K^\prime =\frac{b^{2} -2r}{2b^{2}} -K$$
The capital $F$s are [hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).
These functions are **horrendously** complicated, so I would personally recommend not trying to analyze the general closed form solution of this ODE too much. Your differential equation seems to be some form of a hypergeometric differential equation (very specialized stuff.)

Comment: Thank you. Instead of $b$ it should be $\sigma$. I have already changed it. Do you know how to solve my equation to obtain the solution that you wrote?

Comment: I must admit, I don't. This is some highly specialized differential equation stuff and I am a lowly undergrad. Do some research on "hypergeometric differential equations" and you might find something. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Thank you anyway. Maybe someone else will be more proficient in this topic.